# SaltStack: --failhard for salt-ssh

Tags: saltstack

I would like the execution of `salt-ssh` to cancel on the first error.

I read this: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/failhard.html

But I am using salt master-less with salt-ssh.

Is there a way to cancel on the first error.

Of course I could add '- failhard: True' to every state in my sls files, but I would like to have an easier solution.

Comment: Please leave a comment instead of down-voting. What's wrong with this question?

Comment: You probably didn't write what did you try.

Comment: @MichalSokolowski I wrote what I tried. I read the docs.

Comment: That's my point, pasting a link is not enough but still insufficient to down vote your question IMHO, therefore I up voted it.